# bash function executes php but then pauses / bash function gets stuck

Tags: bash, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I am using WSL (windows subsystem linux) to locally develop PHP files.

I am using the inbuilt PHP server to run them via Ubuntu:

```
php -S localhost:8000
```

I've made a Bashrc function to do this for me but it **pauses** after creating the localhost.

```
phpLocal(){
        php -S localhost:"$1"
        cmd.exe /C start http://localhost:"$1"
}
```

The goal is to run

```
phpLocal 8200
```

and this to open a web browser with the local host running `localhost:8200`.

**The issue**

Bash accepts the command - i.e. creates the localhost server on port 8200, but the browsers does not open it.

[image]

Then when I cancel the command the browser does open it, but because the command has been canceled there is nothing to open..

[image]

I suspect I am missing some in how bash runs functions.

Any help  would be great  -
Wally

-- Requested information

I am calling this function like this

```
phpLocal 8200
```

-- renamed question as I believe it not to be a duplicate, but the answer to the issue to be the same. I think its valuable for people searching broader terms relating to bash functions...

Comment: Can you try `cmd.exe /C "start http://localhost:$1"` ?

Comment: @Wally : Please also show also in your post (not in a screenshot) how you call this function. Also, I would try to run `cmd.exe´ in the background. BTW, there is no such thing as a _**Bashrc** function_. What you have is simply called a _**bash** function_.

Comment: @Wally : Another idea would be to place a `sleep` between the PHP command and the start command.

Comment: @Philippe - Thank you for your suggestion but that didnt work

Comment: @user1934428 Thanks for pointing out the name of the function (newbie mistakes....) - I've updated the answer as per your request. How do you run cmd.exe in the background?

Comment: I don't have WSL, but I would do it like with other programs, i.e. by terminating it with a `&`. However, I would try the `sleep` first. I also would try a `cmd /c start ...` with some other URL (`google.com` or something like this). Another thing worth trying is have two shells open: In one you start the PHP server, and in the other one you start the browser. My gut feeling is that this is really a timing issue, and if I'm right, running in the background won't improve it.

Comment: Did you already try to launch your server in the background, such that the next command gets executed before the server terminates? Try `php -S localhost:"$1"
&`.

Comment: @user1934428 - running in the background worked i.e. phpLocal(){
        php -S localhost:"$1" &
        cmd.exe /C start http://localhost:"$1"
} -- Thank you for your help. Can I ask - what is the & doing in this command?

Comment: If you combine commands by `&`, i.e. `A & B`, `A` is executed in the background, i.e. B is started even if A is still running.

Comment: @user1934428 ah I get it! so its similar to JS needing to run a async function. Since you promoted this answer first did you want to post an answer?

Comment: IMO, Jeff Schaller should get the accepted answer.

Comment: @Wally I understand your point that there *is* uniqueness to this question, but that's likely true of most duplicates.  The problem with allowing duplicates like this is that there are literally an infinite number of possible commands you might want to run in the background in a shell script.  The linked duplicate covers the core issue both in the question and in the answer.  There's just no sense for a separate question/answer for each possible incantation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you execute this function:

```sh
phpLocal(){
        php -S localhost:"$1"
        cmd.exe /C start http://localhost:"$1"
}
```

... the `php` command executes in the foreground. If you want it to continue executing so that the `cmd.exe` line can execute, you could put the `php` line [in the background with the `&` symbol](https://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/bash/manual/html_node/Lists.html#Lists):

```sh
phpLocal(){
        php -S localhost:"$1" &
        cmd.exe /C start http://localhost:"$1"
}
```